# QFileDialog to default to AppData?

Tags: c++, qt, directory, appdata, qfiledialog

In my program, I have a button that opens a getOpenFileName dialog like this:

```
path = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Select region"), "%APPDATA%", tr("region file"));
```

I want the dialog to default to the users AppData folder. All users are running Windows (XP or higher). How could I ensure it defaults to AppData?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use QDesktopServices static method (Qt4):

```
QString path = QDesktopServices::storageLocation(QDesktopServices::DataLocation);
```

In Qt5:

```
QString path = QStandardPaths::standardLocations(QStandardPaths::DataLocation).at(0);
```

To get Roaming folder:

```
QSettings settings(QSettings::IniFormat, QSettings::UserScope, "AppName", "application");
QString location = QFileInfo(settings.fileName()).absolutePath() + "/";
```

In my case path was:

> C:/Users/maxim.makhun/AppData/Roaming/AppName/

Comment: I get an error: storageLocation is not a member of qdesktopservices... and so is datalocation.

Comment: Yes. 5.0.2 and I've included QDesktopServices. I'm looking at the documentation now, and I'm doing exactly that??? hmmm

Comment: I improved my answer. There're some changes in Qt5.

Comment: It defaulted to Appdata/Local. Can I change that to Roaming? or just Appdata?

Comment: Ah. In this case I used QSettings. There were issues with QStandardPaths